# FME - Specify schema name in PostgreSQL database writer (ArcSDE)

Tags: postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, file-geodatabase, fme-form

I am attempting to transfer data from a file geodatabase into an enterprise geodatabase (PostgreSQL) using FME. By default, the writer copies it into either the "public" schema or the "sde" schema. However, I aim to copy the data into a schema of my choice (which is “test” in this example). Although I've attempted to add the schema name before my table name using a dot, as suggested in an older post on this forum, I am still encountering errors.

Error: The error message from ArcObjects is: {DBMS table not found} [stormwater.test._2017_2018_O_M_Assessments]}

The following items exists:

```
PostgreSQL Database Name: stormwater

File Geodatabase Name: _2017_2018_O_M_Assessments

Schema Name: test
```

The writer is set to **create the table if it doesn't exist** (which in my case doesn't exist already).

Please see the attached image for reference.

[image: Workflow Diagram]

Comment: You *can't* specify the schema in table creation -- The ArcSDE API will only use the login name as the schema (and you can't specify it at all). If you aren't connected as login "test", you cannot create a table in schema "test" (and if you're connected as login 'sde', you should create a new login to own data, and connect as that, since no user data should ever be owned by the geodatabase administrator account).